# How fields of strucure arguments in assembly are ordered?

Tags: assembly, x86, dllimport, argument-passing, disassembly

I have an excel script which calls a function from a DLL file. I have opened the DLL file but I could not understand much from it.

The excel script defines the following structures:

```
Public Type Product
    price As Double
    size As Double
    isExpensive As Boolean
    isCheap As Boolean
    isVerified As Boolean
    isPacked As Boolean
    isDelivered As Boolean
End Type

Public Type Pricing
    value1 As Double
    value2 As Double
    value3 As Double
    value4 As Double
End Type

Public Type Receipt
    price As Double
    location_x As Double
    location_y As Double
    time As Double
    gross_weight As Double
    special_weight As Double
    discount As Double
    dispatched As Boolean
    paid As Boolean
End Type

Public Type Location
    reputation As Double
    id As Long
    staffs As Long
    location_x As Double
    location_y As Double
    working_weekends As Boolean
    ventilated As Boolean
End Type

Public Type Output
    future_week1 As Double
    future_week2 As Double
    future_week3 As Double
    future_week4 As Double
    future_week5 As Double
    future_week6 As Double
    future_week7 As Double
    future_week8 As Double
    future_week9 As Double
    future_week10 As Double
    future_week11 As Double
    future_week12 As Double
    future_week13 As Double
    future_week14 As Double
    future_week15 As Double
    future_week16 As Double
    future_week17 As Double
    future_week18 As Double
End Type
```

and calls the following function

```
EstimateFuture myProduct, pricing1, pricing2, receipt1, location, myoutput
```

This function receives `myProduct`, `pricing1`, `pricing2`, `receipt1`, and `location` as input and it puts output in `myoutput`.

No matter if these structures are well designed or not. I need to understand the order of each field in memory.

The assembly beginning for estimation function is as following:

```
EstimateFuture:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    and esp,FFFFFFF8h
    sub esp,000000A0h
    push    esi
    mov esi,[ebp+08h]
    push    edi
    mov ecx,0000000Ch
    mov edi,L1000F198
    rep movsd
    mov esi,[ebp+0Ch]
    mov ecx,00000008h
    mov edi,L1000F250
    rep movsd
    mov esi,[ebp+10h]
    mov ecx,00000008h
    mov edi,L1000F208
    rep movsd
    mov esi,[ebp+14h]
    mov ecx,00000010h
    mov edi,L1000F1C8
    rep movsd
    mov esi,[ebp+18h]
    mov ecx,0000000Ah
    mov edi,L1000F228
    rep movsd
    ...
```

Apparently the code above is trying to store arguments into its memory. Here we have six arguments and five `rep movsd`. Maybe because five variables are input and the last one is not.

But what I don't understand is that in no way the addresses match the variables. Neither according to their size nor their label segmentation. Either arguments are stored in direct way or reverse way, they do not match with the addresses as following:

```
L1000F198:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F1A0:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F1A8:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F1AC:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F1AE:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F1B2:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F1B4:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F1B8:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F1C0:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F1C8:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F1D0:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F1D8:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F1E0:
        dq  0000000000000000h
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F1F0:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F1F8:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F200:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F202:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F208:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F210:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F218:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F220:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F228:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F230:
        dd  00000000h
L1000F234:
        dd  00000000h
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F240:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F248:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F24A:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F250:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F258:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F260:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F268:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F270:
        dd  00000000h
L1000F274:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F278:
        dd  00000000h
L1000F27C:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F284:
        dd  00000000h
L1000F288:
        dd  00000000h
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F290:
        dd  00000000h
L1000F294:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F298:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
```

I do not know the original language of this DLL file or the name or version of the compiler.

Could some one please fill this puzzle for me?

```
address of myProduct.price = ?
address of myProduct.size = ?
address of myProduct.isExpensive = ?
address of myProduct.isCheap = ?
address of myProduct.isVerified = ?
address of myProduct.isPacked = ?
address of myProduct.isDelivered = ?

address of pricing1.value1 = ?
address of pricing1.value2 = ?
address of pricing1.value3 = ?
address of pricing1.value4 = ?

address of pricing2.value1 = ?
address of pricing2.value2 = ?
address of pricing2.value3 = ?
address of pricing2.value4 = ?

address of receipt1.price = ?
address of receipt1.location_x = ?
address of receipt1.location_y = ?
address of receipt1.time = ?
address of receipt1.gross_weight = ?
address of receipt1.special_weight = ?
address of receipt1.discount = ?
address of receipt1.dispatched = ?
address of receipt1.paid = ?


address of location.reputation = ?
address of location.id = ?
address of location.staffs = ?
address of location.location_x = ?
address of location.location_y = ?
address of location.working_weekends = ?
address of location.ventilated = ?

address of myoutput.future_week1 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week2 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week3 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week4 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week5 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week6 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week7 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week8 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week9 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week10 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week11 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week12 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week13 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week14 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week15 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week16 = ?
address of myoutput.future_week17 = ?
```

**Update**

Thanks to matan7890, now I know that the address of `myProduct` is at `L1000F228`:

```
L1000F228:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F230:
        dd  00000000h
L1000F234:
        dd  00000000h
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F240:
        dq  0000000000000000h
L1000F248:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L1000F24A:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
```

it means:

```
address of myProduct.price = L1000F228 (8 bytes)
address of myProduct.size = L1000F230 (8 bytes)
address of myProduct.isExpensive = L1000F238 (4 bytes) -----> No Label
address of myProduct.isCheap = L1000F23C (4 bytes) -----> No Label
address of myProduct.isVerified = L1000F240 (4 bytes)
address of myProduct.isPacked = L1000F244 (4 bytes) -----> No Label
address of myProduct.isDelivered = L1000F248 (4 bytes)
```

Here, the problem is that `myProduct.isExpensive`, `myProduct.isCheap` and `myProduct.isPacked` have no label at their begining.

Other problems are that

`myProduct.price` is made of 8 single bytes instead of single 8 bytes.

`myProduct.size` must be 8 bytes but after 4 bytes another label is introduced.

It seems labels are not on their right place.

Comment: Working on it, wait a second for my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, be aware that the arguments that you pass are ordered in reverse order to what you think in the stack. For example, your first variable `myProduct` is in `[ebp+18h]`.

Also, Be aware that in vb `Boolean` is 4 bytes and not 1. So, your Product type is 36 bytes, `Pricing` is 32 bytes and so on. The `movsd` opcode copies 4 bytes at a time (dwords). By reading the `rep`s, it seems that your arguments are not in the right order, because the second arguments copies 64 bytes (4 * 10h == 4 * 16 = 64), like your `Receipt` type. It seems that the right order of the arguments, only by reffering from the wanted sizes, are:

```
EstimateFuture myProduct, receipt1, pricing1, pricing2, location, myoutput
```

That means `myProduct` is seems to be in L1000F228 and the coming 40 bytes. Be aware that your structure is only 36 bytes, which means you may missing one `Boolean` member in that type.

From here you can calculate by yourself :)

Comment: are fields of structures also stored in reverse order of the field?

Comment: Please notice that the addresses are not assigned in order. L1000F228 is assigned the last. but L1000F250 is after it.

Comment: Your problem now is that the labels you have are not synced with your structures? That doesn't matter, because a set of 8 bytes one after each other are the same as one dq. The memory is linear. I don't know what is your disassembler, but I believe it just doesn't know how your structures look like.

For your first comment, the structures themself should be the same like you code. Just be aware that the numbers themself are probably little endian.

Comment: Thanks very much. So by `little endian` you mean that in `myProduct` structure `isDelivered` is stored before  `price` so `L1000F228` is the beginning address of `myProduct.isDelivered`?

Comment: Little endian means that in a multibyte primitive type, like a DWORD, the lowest byte is at the lowest address. The opposite (big endian) means that the highest byte is at the lowest address. It does not change the ordering of the fields, only the ordering of the bytes in, say, a double or an int. X86 processors are little endian.